# OpenGL ES 2 pinch to zoom by center point Android

Tags: android, math, matrix, kotlin, opengl-es-2.0

I have problems with implementing of pinch to zoom functionality in my app.

Currently zoom works correctly, but I want to move center of the zoom from center of surface to middle point of touch.

Here are parts of my **Renderer** class:

```
override fun onSurfaceChanged(gl: GL10?, width: Int, height: Int) {

    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    aspectRatioGlobal = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
    top = PORTRAIT_NEAR_LIMIT * Math.tan(60 * (Math.PI / 360.0)).toFloat()
    bottom = -top;
    left = bottom * aspectRatioGlobal
    right = top * aspectRatioGlobal
    Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar)

    ....

override fun onDrawFrame(gl: GL10?) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    Matrix.setIdentityM(intersectionUnprojectionMatrix, 0)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(intersectionUnprojectionMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, cameraZ, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
    if (!onImageLoaded) {
        resizeImageOnStart(rectangle?.getImageParameters(context)!!)
        displayImage()
        onImageLoaded = true
    } else {
        Matrix.setIdentityM(modelViewMatrix, 0)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(modelViewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, cameraZ, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
        // Matrix.translateM(modelViewMatrix, 0, cameraX, cameraY, 0f)
        Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, currentImageWidth, currentImageHeight, 1f)
        Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 1f)
        // Matrix.translateM(modelViewMatrix, 0, -cameraX, -cameraY, 0f)
        Matrix.multiplyMM(resultMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0)
    }
    rectangle?.draw(resultMatrix, context)

    ....

fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector) {
    var center = getWorldCoordinatesByScreenCoordinates(detector.focusX, detector.focusY)
    cameraX = center.x
    cameraY = center.y
    this.scaleFactor = detector.scaleFactor
```

Current logic:

- **ScaleGestureDetector** catches event and sends it to the Renderer
- Renderer sets **scaleFactor** and calculates world coordinates of touch center (**getWorldCoordinatesByScreenCoordinates** method works correctly)
- onDrawFrame displayes modified data.

The main problem is that I can't understand how correctly transform object. I was trying to translate the object, scale it and translate back again(translate lines are now commented), but this doesn't work.
Please help!

Comment: Don't know enough OpenGL or Kotlin to add an answer, plus I work mainly in the 2D Matrix class.  If the scale is focused on the center, then the solution is to translate the touch point to the center (touch minus center?), do the scaling, then translate the center back to the touch point (center minus touch).  I might have the subtractions backwards depending on how your matrices are set up.